# Firebase Deep link not working in background in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using firebase deep linking for Android, but it does not work properly in background.
Here is my code that I am using

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(SplashActivity.this, SplashActivity.this)
            .addApi(AppInvite.API)
            .build();
boolean autoLaunchDeepLink = false;
AppInvite.AppInviteApi.getInvitation(mGoogleApiClient, this, autoLaunchDeepLink)
        .setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<AppInviteInvitationResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull AppInviteInvitationResult result) {
}}}
```

It's working when Application is not in Background, but If app is in background it open the app but `onResult` method of `ResultCallback` does not call. That's why I am unable to navigate application screen according to requirement.

Comment: Has anyone managed to get around this? I tried using: `android:pathPrefix="/gizmos"` and `android:pathPattern=".*"` however I haven't managed to solve it.

Comment: need to wait to call the callback due to a race condition. cant figure out how to get the callback to call after ive got a token from my api.

Comment: Did you solved it? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you put your `AppInvite.AppInviteApi.getInvitation()` code?
It should resides in `Activity` which is defined in your `AndroidManifest` with appropriate Intent-Filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:host="example.com" android:scheme="http"/>
    <data android:host="example.com" android:scheme="https"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: I have already put the code, It's working if app is not in background. But if application instance is in background then app is not working properly. onResult method of ResultCallback does not called. But on create nethod is called of activity where I have wrote down the code.

Comment: The method is in onCreate() method of activity.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the reason why this is happening was because the deeplink was being handled in the first activity which is launched. In reality for this to work, it needs to be handled in a second activity like this:

```
    <activity>
        android:name=".activity.FirstActivity"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity>
        android:name=".activity.SecondActivity"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="https" 
                  android:host="www.example.com" 
                  android:pathPrefix="/extra"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This worked for me.